# If any bounded sequence in an ordered field K has a subsequential limit in K, is K a complete ordered field?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

Let K be an ordered field. If any bounded sequence in K has a subsequential limit in K, is K a complete ordered field? (i.e. satisfying any one of the equivalent definitions of a complete ordered field.) (If you know the answer you may give hints first.)

Comment: Which definition of "complete" are you using? There are two standard definitions (that I know of) in this context.

Comment: @CameronBuie: I personally prefer taking having the least-upper-bound property as the definition of a complete ordered filed. And according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers this is equivalent to Cauchy completeness + the Archimedean property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for the earlier, completely wrong answer.

Here's the approach you want to take. First of all, show that any sequence in an ordered field has a monotone subsequence. Thus, bounded sequences must have subsequential limits if and only if bounded monotone sequences converge.

Now, show that if $\Bbb K$ is an ordered field in which bounded monotone sequences converge, then $\Bbb K$ is Archimedean. Indeed, if not, then the sequence of natural numbers in the field is bounded and monotone, so converges to some $L\in\Bbb K.$ You should be able to show that, for example, $L-1$ is an upper bound for the natural numbers in $\Bbb K,$ but $L-1<L,$ and so this contradicts the convergence.

Finally, show that if $\Bbb K$ is an ordered field in which bounded monotone sequences converge, then Cauchy sequences converge, and you're home free! If you need a proof that a Cauchy-complete Archimedean ordered field is Dedekind complete, there's a nice one as part of Theorem 3.11 of [this paper](http://digitalcommons.calpoly.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1004&context=mathsp).

Comment: Excuse me but a newbie question: Does this ordered field $\mathbb{R}(x)$ satisfies the hypothesis that any bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}(x)$ has a subsequential limit in $\mathbb{R}(x)$?

Comment: Nope! Not at all. I was considering Cauchy-completeness equivalent to monotone convergence, but this need not be true for non-Archimedean fields! This answer should do the trick.